# How to throttle performance of a VHD (Virtual Hard Disk )

Tags: windows, performance, disk-utility

I'd like to be able to throttle the performance of Reads/Writes on some of my disks. While I know it might be pretty difficult to control that on actual Physical disks, is there any tool which can simulate extremely slow speeds on a Virtual Disk.
I can create Virtual Disk using Disk Management but I can't seem to find a way to throttle performance.

I'd like to create Virtual Disks in a similar fashion (don't care what tool I use) but I want to control the performance of the disk.

If this is not possible, then can I at least do something to simulate this scenario ?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'd like to test a tool I'm developing (a really small tool which reads data from sources with different read/write speeds). I don't to do this by taxing my VHD with actual writes/reads (cause then it wouldn't be a simulation)

Comment: vmware seams to allow limits: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1038241 Try this.